# How do I make a gameobject I am placing collide with an already place gameobject?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to place a gameobject, but if I try to place it on the ground it does not collide with other placed objects and vice versa. The object I am placing has an inactive Box Collider, because if it is active before placing it, unity tries to place it on itself.

```
private GameObject currentPlaceableHouse;

private void MoveCurrentPlaceableHouseToMouse()
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hitInfo;

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitInfo))
        {
            currentPlaceableHouse.transform.position = hitInfo.point;
            currentPlaceableHouse.transform.rotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.up, hitInfo.normal);
        }
    }
```

This is my code, it detects where to place the object. I already tried OnCollision, but if I add a rigidbody to the gameobject I want to place without using gravity, it floats up as soon as I place it.

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want the objects to physically fall on top of each other or stack on top of each other regardless of the collider?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html) is your friend.
For anything collision related, this is your goto. You need to see the matrix at the end and figure out what your scene looks like and whether or not it makes sense that you're not getting collisions. It really depends on how you want the placeable House to be colliding. If it's mostly a non-moveable thing that other moveable things collide with, then make it a static collider and only disable it while placement. If you want it to collide with other things and like, fall off to the side and roll, then you need to add a rigidbody to it and use Kinematic while placement.

Either way, in order for two objects to collide with each other, the bare minimum for both is to have an active collider, as it means they are active physics objects. The differences lie in the configurations of either side, whether you also have a RigidBody and whether it's Kinematic and finally the Layer Collision Matrix which states whether object A (from Layer A) can collide with object B (from Layer C) at all. If they can't, no matter whether they have colliders, have Rigidbodies etc, they won't ever collide.